# How to ignore foreign key related exceptions in doctrine/symfony without having the entity manager destroyed?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I've got a program whose database is synced with an external database (unidirectional, the other program/database is always the sender).

Everytime the sync takes place, I create, update or delete records. The other program always sends all its entities of the same kind (e. g. all Cars) at once.
These records are often used via foreign key constraints inside my database. Creating and updating is fine, but deleting records does not work. I need to delete the records on my side, which are not present on the other side any more.

After my create/update routine, I've collected all the records I need to delete. I don't want to delete the records which are still in use inside other tables and only give a warning, hence the foreign key constraints are needed. I know I could make them nullable or disable foreign key checks or something like that, but this is not what I want.

Walking through these objects and trying to delete them destroys my entity manager when the first exception due to a foreign key constraint is thrown. I know there are constraints, I know they prevent records from being deleted when they are still in use - this is exactly what I want. But I want the entity manager to continue working. I get the infamous "The Entity Manager is closed." message.

I've seen a couple of so-called fixes, which all maybe worked on earlier symfony versions (I'm on 6.2), including resetting the entity manager, injecting doctrine and doing something, creating a new entity manager (then the objects are not attached to it any more ...). Is there any workaround here?

Basically, I just want to delete a bunch of records one by one and not have my program/entity manager be killed if a record can't be deleted due to still being used as a foreign key somewhere in the database.

Some made-up example code:

```
<?php
$cars = $em->getRepository(Car::class)->findAll();

foreach($cars as $car) {
  if($car->shouldBeDeleted()) {
    $em->remove($car);
    $em->flush(); // doesn't matter where it's placed
  }
}

$em->flush(); // doesn't matter where it's placed
```

Try-Catch let's me see there's an error, but doesn't prevent the entity manager from breaking, of course. A method like `$car->isStillUsedSomewhereInTheDatabase()` would be okay, too, but only if it can be solved inside doctrine/symfony. I don't want to maintain a list of possible occurences of my records inside other tables ...

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution via trial-and-error. The key was to get the ManagerRegistry and call resetManager(). This seems to finally reset the manager in a way that you can continue using it.

```
// $registry comes from an injected Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry
/* @var $entityManager EntityManager */
$entityManager = $registry->getManager();

// some stuff

// try-catch is inside a loop which walks through the objects to be deleted
try {
    if(!$entityManager->isOpen()) {
        $registry->resetManager();

        // Refetch the object (or else it'd be detached)
        $objectFromDatbaseToBeDeleted = $entityManager->getRepository(Some::class)->find($objectFromDatbaseToBeDeleted);
    }

    $entityManager->remove($objectFromDatbaseToBeDeleted);
    $entityManager->flush();
    $numDeletedObjects++;
} catch(Exception $e) {
    $numNonDeletedObjects++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put your code in a try/catch statement and every time check if the entity Manager is still open. If not, recreate the Entity Manager

```php
if (!$this->entityManager->isOpen()) {
    $this->entityManager = $this->entityManager->create(
        $this->entityManager->getConnection(),
        $this->entityManager->getConfiguration()
    );
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you actually tried your suggested solution?  I ask because EntityManager::create is a static method and calling static methods dynamically is usually discouraged.  I am also unsure how your proposed solution solves the problem of entities not being attached anymore (as stated in the question).

Comment: Yes, I'm now getting the ```Detached entity App\\Entity\\xyz@1144 cannot be removed``` error. And the possibility to call ->create() on an EM object was removed some time ago, so you have to call it statically as Cerad stated.

Comment: I can't even think of a workaround. HTTP DELETE every single entity through my API? Create a service which deletes single entitys via ID and always initializes a new EntityManager? Is it such an edge case to delete a collection of entities one by one?